# Excluir archivos .pdf vía rsync en java

Tags: java, eclipse, rsync

Hola estoy trabajando con Rsync en Incluir o Excluir archivos específicos tengo un problema con la exclusión de archivos .pdf, ya que en mi código pongo lo siguiente

```
public class App extends Window{
private static String path; 
public static void daemon() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Conecting to server ....");
    RSync rsync = new RSync();
    String nombUser="";
    //SSH VIA RSYNC
    rsync.setOptions(new String[]{"-avz","--exclude","*.png","/home/madai/Música/","/Descargas/Windows_Sync_Usuario-20190611T200625Z-001/Windows_Sync_Usuario/crdntls","ssh",path,nombUser+"192.168.2.219:rsync"});
    ConsoleOutputProcessOutput output = new ConsoleOutputProcessOutput();
    output.monitor(rsync.builder());
}
```

En la cual yo especifico la carpeta destino donde recibirá los archivos excepto los .pdf, sin embargo en la consola me sale lo siguiente y en la carpeta que designe para recibir me añade todo los archivos incluidos los PDF. Si alguien me puede orientar se lo agradezco mucho, es la primera vez que manejo este tipo de sincronización de archivos por rsync. 
[image: Salida de consola]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te hacen falta las comillas simples en tu parámetro *.pdf

```
rsync.setOptions(new String[]{"-avz","--exclude","'*.pdf'","/home/madai/Música","crdntls","ssh",path,nombUser+"192.168.2.219:rsync"});
```

Según la [documentación de Rsync](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) el parámetro **exclude necesita un patrón**

> --exclude=PATTERN
>       This option is a simplified form of the --filter option that defaults to an exclude rule and does not allow the full rule-parsing
>   syntax of normal filter rules.
>
> ```
> See the FILTER RULES section for detailed information on this option.
> ```

Algunos ejemplo que se encuentran en el mismo documento son los siguientes:

```
rsync -avC --include=foo.o -f :C --exclude='*.old' a/ b
rsync -avuzb --exclude '*~' samba:samba/ .
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, sin embargo me aloja todos los archivos incluyendo los que debe de excluir :( Estuve cambiando algunas lineas de código y me excluye los archivos, sin embargo en la carpeta que está dentro de mi proyecto "crdntls" me aloja todos los archivos. Pero después de mi IP de servidor seguido de los ":" puse una carpeta "rsync" en esa carpeta sin embargo me hace la exclusión de archivos.